# Microsoft Graph API create Teams chat on behalf of user from backend

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, chat

I am trying to create functionality to create a new chat on behalf of the user from the NodeJS backend. The app used has admin consent to utilize the `Chat.Create`. I am trying to fetch the token with following code:

```js
  const authResponse = await fetch(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
      client_id: clientId,
      scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/Chat.Create/.default',
      client_secret: clientSecret,
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    }),
  });
```

I get the following error:

```
error: invalid_resource
error_description: AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://graph.microsoft.com/Chat.Create was not found in the tenant named <tenant>. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant
```

If I change the scope to be `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`, I actually get the access token but the chat creation fails with `403 Forbidden`.

As I have understood, the token generated this way only applies to permissions that are on Application level, not the ones that are Delegated.

Is there any way to do this completely in the backend without any user action from the UI?